# isocpus - intel skylake, redhat 7.7 number of cpus confusion

Tags: cpu-usage, cpu-architecture

We've got 2 skylake processors i9-9960x (16 core) and i9-7920x (12 core), hyperthreading off in both. i'm trying to set the isolcpus to 2-15 and and 2-11 respectively, but when i run the command:

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/possible` on the 12-core shows `0-67`

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/possible` on the 16-core shows `0-71`

How do I make sense of these numbers?

Comment: Any reason you are using `possible` rather than `present`?

Comment: Whoops, `present` gives me the right answer. How is `possible` different from `present`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some systems allow you to `hotplug` additional cpus. The linux kernel allocates resources at boot time for these potential additional cpus, and this is reflected in the `possible`. The cpus which are currently connected are listed in the `present` file, and the ones which are online or offline are listed in the `online` and `offline` files.

Depending on what you want to do, the `present` or `online` files are usually the right choice.